# How do I rename specific columns in one data frame based on another

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have one dataframe as follows:

`df1:
   ACCOUNT_NAME Units GM
1. Sejal        12    12
2. Mohata       10    15`

And another dataframe as:

`df2:
  INPUT_FIELD    TRANSL
1. ACCOUNT_NAME  Account Name
2. GM            Gross Margin
3. REVENUE       Revenue
4. BU            Business Unit`

I want to rename the columns of df1 to the TRANSL values in df2, if the values are present in INPUT_FIELD.

I have tried:
`df1.columns = df1.columns.map(df2.set_index('INPUT_FIELD')['TRANSL'].get)`

It renames the columns as:
['Account Name', None, 'Gross Margin']

I want to rename the columns selectively without using equal operator, as this table might grow in the future.

Comment: to rename columns you can pass in a dictionary of key value pairs `df.rename(columns={'Transl' : 'Units'})`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Series.to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_dict.html) method to convert a series `df2["TRANSL"]` to  a dictionary `mappings` and then you can use [`DataFrame.rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) method to rename the columns of `df1` by passing the `mappings` dict to `columns` argument of `rename` method.

Use:

```
mappings = df2.set_index("INPUT_FIELD")["TRANSL"].to_dict()
df1.rename(columns=mappings, inplace=True)
print(df1)
```

This prints:

```
  Account Name  Units  Gross Margin
0        Sejal     12            12
1       Mohata     10            15
```

Comment: creating a dictionary will increase latency and I want to do it on the fly, is there a more optimized approach than this?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily build the dict comprehension from `df2.values`:

```
df1.rename(columns={i:j for i,j in df2.values})
```

gives:

```
    Account Name  Units  Gross Margin
1.0        Sejal     12            12
2.0       Mohata     10            15
```

---

Rename also accept a mapper function, so you can use:

```
def mapper(x):
    trans = df2.loc[df2.INPUT_FIELD == x, 'TRANSL']
    return trans.iat[0] if len(trans)>0 else x
df1.rename(columns = mapper)
```

In my tests (using timeit) it is longer than the dict way. It is only faster when you have more than 1000 rows in `df2` and when the column names are in the first rows, because then it does not scan the whole values array.

Comment: creating a dictionary will increase latency and I want to do it on the fly, is there a more optimized approach than this?